# Glue crawler exclude patterns

Tags: aws-glue

I have an s3 bucket that I'm trying to crawl and catalog. The format is something like this, where the SQL files are DDL queries (`CREATE TABLE` statements) that match the schema of the different data files, i.e. `data1`, `data2`, etc.)

```
s3://my-bucket/somedata/20180101/data1/stuff.txt.gz
s3://my-bucket/somedata/20180101/data2/stuff.txt.gz
s3://my-bucket/somedata/20180101/data1.sql
s3://my-bucket/somedata/20180101/data2.sql  
s3://my-bucket/somedata/20180102/data1/stuff.txt.gz
s3://my-bucket/somedata/20180102/data2/stuff.txt.gz
...
```

I just want to catalog `data1`, so I am trying to use the [exclude patterns in the Glue Crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html) - see below - i.e. `*.sql` and `data2/*`.

[image]

Unfortunately the crawler is still classifying everything within the root path of `s3://my-bucket/somedata/`. I can live with having `data2` cataloged; I'm most concerned/annoyed by the `sql` files.

Anyone have experience with exclude patterns or able to point out what is wrong here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `*` in the exclude pattern does not cross directories, but the `**` does span across directories.

To exclude all `.sql` files you can use: `**.sql`

The fullpath of your `data2/*` exclusion is `s3://my-bucket/somedata/data2/*`, but its missing your date partition folders.  This is remedied by adding a `*` in front.

To exclude the `data2/` directories use: `*/data2/*`

Answer (score 2):

Also, to exclude folder pattern -
Exclude Pattern: folder_n**/** (excludes all folders starting with "folder_n")