# Glue crawler exclude all files except the ones that match a pattern

Tags: aws-glue

I have a crawler for an S3 bucket in AWS. I would like my crawler to only include files that match certain pattern, but the problem is that pattern-matching only works for excluding files according to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html#crawler-data-stores-exclude). A similar question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812463/glue-crawler-exclude-patterns).

Supose I have an include path like this one: `s3://my-datalake/projects/`.
Now I want to exclude everything that does not contain the pattern `my-pattern` in its name.

I've tried the following exclude pattern with no success: `!my-pattern*`

Is this even possible to achieve?