# How to skip files with specific extension on Redshift external tables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a partitioned location on S3 with data I want to read via Redshift External Table, which I create with the SQL statement `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE...`.

Only thing is that I have some metadata files within these partitions with, for example, extension `.txt` while the data I'm reading is `.json`.

Is it possible to inform Redshift to skip those files, in a similar manner to Glue Crawler exclude patterns?
e.g. [Glue crawler exclude patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812463/glue-crawler-exclude-patterns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try using the pseudocolumns in the SQL and excluding based on the path name?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE_usage.html

```
create external table as ....

select .....
where "$path" like '%.json'
```